# GPO Uninstall Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, uninstallation

How to uninstall Sharepoint Designer via Group Policy, or an easy way to mass uninstall in an enterprise environment.  DTC doesn't seem to like uninstalling Microsoft products.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the policy that installed the SharePoint Designer, you have to open group policy management editor, then go to computer/user configuration (depending on which one you used) -> policies-> software settings -> software installation-> there you will have your installed software, right click it, go to properties, now in deployement you have a checkbox "Uninstall this application when it falls out of scope of management" . If you tick it, it will uninstall the application, if the computers/users won't have this policy applied to their group.

If its not installed via GPOI think it would be quite easy to create an installing GPO, apply it and then remove it from the scope of management, I think it should work :)